# How do i call @Test (POM-data driven method) in the 1st class from the @beforemethod in the 2nd class

Tags: java, selenium, pageobjects, data-driven-tests

```
//Action Class(LoginPage.java) of Data Driven Method from First Class
public void login(String uname, String pwd) {
    username.sendKeys(uname);
    password.sendKeys(pwd);
    submit.click();
}

//First Class(LoginPageTest.java)
@DataProvider
public Object[][] loginData() {
    Object data[][]=TestUtil.getTestData(sheetname);
    return data;
}

@Test(priority=2,dataProvider="loginData")
public void HomePageLoginTest(String un, String pd) {
    page.login(un, pd);
    String text = page.validateLoginPageTitle();
    Assert.assertEquals(text, "Login: Mercury Tours");
    page.flightPageClick();
}

//Second Class(FlighFinderTest.java)- Where i need to call the method in @BeforeMethod
@BeforeMethod()
public void setUp() {
    initialization();
    page = new LoginPage();
    fpage= page.login(uname, pwd);
    }
```

Comment: we do not call [@Test] methods, they are auto picked by testng for execution, questions is not cleared , tell which method you want to call in [@BeforeClass ] annotation

Comment: i want to call HomePageLoginTest method in @BeforeMethod

Comment: We call generic methods and not methods with [@Test] annotation. You need to write different method without annotation to achieve this.

Comment: You may have to paste full code